# creating counter variable inside es6 class used by static methods recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

having a static recursive method , where i need to have a counter that should be declared.

please see the below snippet what am i doing any wrong here

one static method extracts data and another static method formats the data into a proper format

```
class Method(){
  constructor(payload){
    this.data = Method.extractData(payload)
  }

  static recursiveFunction(list, object ={}, methods){
    // recursive logic at a point 
    if(condtionNotSatisfied){
      this.recursiveFunction([value])
    }else{
      // dont call recursive function
      console.log(this.counter) // giving some times 8, 24
      this.counter = this.counter + 1
    }
  }

  static extractData(payload){
    return this.recursiveFunction(payload.list, {}, payload.methods)
  }

  Method.counter = -1;

}

module.exports = Method
```

how can i declare a varibale outside which can be used **recursiveFunction**

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Method(){
  constructor(payload){
    this.data = Method.extractData(payload)
  }

  static recursiveFunction(list, object ={}, methods){
    if (Method.counter === undefined){
       Method.counter = 0; //initialize here
    }
    // recursive logic at a point 
    if(condtionNotSatisfied){
      this.recursiveFunction([value])
    }else{
      // dont call recursive function
      console.log(Method.counter) // giving some times 8, 24
      Method.counter = Method.counter + 1
    }
  }

  static extractData(payload){
    return this.recursiveFunction(payload.list, {}, payload.methods)
  }

  Method.counter = -1;

}

module.exports = Method
```

Comment: getting static counter = 0 as unexpected token

Comment: but i dont want any method i just need a variable why i need to call function, like how we have the counter basically counter variable will be sitting outiside the loop, in my case i am using a recursive function so my counter variable needs to sit outside of the method thats the question

Comment: You can just initialize the counter in any method, like `Abc.counter = 0` then access it anywhere trough `Abc.counter` call. The above is just a representation of the goal

Comment: can you update my snippet of code ? with your correct answer

Comment: should i need a Method.counter = -1 at last ?

Comment: Not really, I suppose you don't.

Comment: Try with the edit I've made. I moved the initialization in the static method.